# C++ directive spelling error

Tags: c++

I have made a rather obvious spelling mistake with directive

```
#if definded foo
```

and I received no error message from the compiler. As I understood,
'defined' is a special argument, so I guessed some sytax error should be raised. Am I wrong?

Comment: If a pre-processor thing - the compiler does not get a look in

Comment: It depends on whether `foo` is defined, and how.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I understand that it behaves according to the standard. What i still cannot understand: when otherwise C++ is strictly requires definition, and verifies types; why is it good that such an obvious mistype even does not deserve a warning? (I always hated that similar mistypes resulted in FORTRAN automatically created new variables)